# How do I link to other pages created dynamically?

Tags: php, html, mysql, hyperlink, anchor

I have a services.php page, and I am using a for loop to create the different services content of the page using information from a MySQL database.

```
<?php for ($i=0; $i < $numberOfRecords; $i++) { ?>

<div class="download-div">

    //this line below creates the anchor with the correct id
    <a id="<?= $scroll ?>" name="<?= $scroll ?>"></a>
    <h1><?= $service[$i] ?></h1>
    <p><textarea spellcheck="true" class="service-text" name="description<?= $i ?>"><?= $description[$i] ?></textarea></p>
    <p class="current-file">Current file: <?= $image[$i] ?></p>
    <input type="file" class="browse" name="image<?= $i ?>">
    <div class="img-wide">
        <img src="upload/<?= $image[$i] ?>">
    </div>

</div>

<?php } ?>
```

The loop creates 10 different service section, each with the name of the service, description, and an image.

When I click on the anchor tag on another page ( I.E. <'a href="services.php#reforestation"> ) that is supposed to link to the id of the a tag in each section, it just goes to the top of the services.php page. However, when I click the link again, it goes to the section of the page I want it to go to. (I.E. <'a id="reforestation" name ="reforestation"> )

It's as if the browser doesn't see the anchor id's until the page has been loaded/ created. Then once it is loaded, it will go to the area of the page I want once I click the anchor tag.

Is there a way around this problem?

Comment: does not really make much sense to me.

Comment: The link in the nav bar <a href="services.php#reforestation">Reforestation</a> doesn't send you to the part of the page where the id is reforestation, it just sends you to the top of the page. But when you click it again when you are on the services.php page, it will work and send you down to where the id is reforestation

Comment: there is no logical reason why that should happen, php is server side so that should not be an issue, any JS here? can you give us a link we can test?

Comment: I'm currently just hosting it on a local wamp server

Comment: often have same problem...anchor tags sometime works and then not.

Comment: I might need to try forcing the page to refresh itself almost instantly once a user is navigated to it in order to get it to work. the url does say http://localhost/forestry2/forestry/services.php#reforestation when going to the page, it just doesn't actually go to the correct id unless you click reload, or click the same link from the nav bar again.

Comment: It just started working now, and I did nothing. What???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it is navigating to another page. I would use javascript on the page to check if we have a hash in the windows address bar. The below function can pull that hash.

```
window.onload = function() {
  if(window.location.hash) {
    var hash = window.location.hash;
    return hash.substring(1); // remove #
    //Once you have this hash you can scroll your page to that element
    location.hash = "#" + hash;
  }
}
```

If you prefer the above in functions, you could use something like below

```
function scrollTo(hash) {
  location.hash = "#" + hash;
}

function getHash() {
  var hash = window.location.hash;
  return hash.substring(1); // remove #
}

window.onload = function() {
  if(window.location.hash) {
    scrollTo(getHash());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the name= attribute as I have had issues with this in some browsers having both and make sure that you have no other id="reforestation" in your document(such as in a menu) it suppose to go to any tag that has a matching id= (according to HTML5 specs). Also make sure that you are not scrolling or doing any input as this will disrupt the scroll action. Check that it does the same in other browsers.